# Oracle Express Date Not Valid

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to insert this line; however, it keeps on saying date not valid. Any reasons why or I'm doing anything wrong?

INSERT INTO ORDERS
VALUES
('21610','20-OCT-2010','356');

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the date string to a date.

```
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES ('21610',to_date('20-OCT-2010', 'dd-mon-yyyy'),'356');
```

Comment: Is there a reason why the code I inserted didn't work or my book got it wrong?

Comment: Oracle will automatically convert some strings to dates, but not all.  It may also depend on your NLS setting witch may differ from the book author.